# How to Embed audio files to cells in Excel? (in Android)

Tags: audio, microsoft-excel

I have a table of alphabets, phonetics, and word examples.

I want to embed the pronunciation of each cell,
so I can press it and it plays the audio file in-app.

Is this possible?
If not, is there any other way I can do it *(a table with embedded audio)*?